# Matplotlib Histogram not showing graph properly

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a list of timestamp in this format: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 6, 54, 46, 535000) for a day.

I want to create a histogram for every 15mins in the day i.e.e 00:00-00:15, 00:15-00:30,00:30-00:45 etc. In all there will be 96 bins (24 hrs*4 bins).

This is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(100, 200))
plt.title('Shift Distribution', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Number of shipments', fontsize=15)
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize='small')
plt.hist(x_data, bins=96)
plt.show()
```

But this is what I am getting:

[image: Histogram]

My objective is to get a histogram which starts from time 00:00 and having range of 15mins and hence spanning out till 23:59. Any idea how to get such a format.

Comment: By setting the interval，it may be can produce right figure. You can upload your data if possible. I can try what I help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `hist` scales the bins' range to the minimum and maximum of your data. According to [the hist API](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist), you can change this by passing in a `range` keyword argument, e.g., `range=[beginningOfDay, endOfDay]`; where `beginningOfDay` and `endOfDay` would have to be in the same format as your data, I believe.